# Mixpanel: Is there a way to link to an user profile?

Tags: mixpanel

I'm developing a web console to control much of the operations on my company. We heavily use Mixpanel and keep some info in the Mixpanel user profile. I need to be able to directly link to each of these profiles from my web console. I have the alias used to create the profile, but I don't have Mixpanel's unique Id. For example:

```
<a href="http://mixpanel.com/some/path/given/alias">Some user</a>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score -2):

Mixpanel automatically generate its distinct id. You must only once call `mixpanel.alias('unique_key')` where as you must use `mixpanel.identify('unique_key ')` everytime for sending the events to mixpanel that will automatically link to the auto generated mixpanel distinct id.

Comment: Completely unrelated

Comment: Can you please explain how it is unrelated. I tried to provide solution according to what i understand from your question.

Comment: Mixpanel uses always a distinct ID underneath. When a new user arrives to your page, Mixpanel creates a distinct ID for her. When she signs up, you associate an alias, an id from your DB from example. In my question, I'm not storing the Mixpanel generated ID, so I need to be able to link to Mixpanel user's profile by alias. Sorry if the question was not clear enough.

Comment: You donot need to store mixpanel generated distinct id. You can also link yo mixpanel user profile with `mixpanel.identify('unique_key')` . unique_key refers to the same key or id you used in `mixpanel.alias()`. Now everytime you call `mixpanel.identify('unique_key')`, it will be linked to mixpanel profile with unique_key . If you are searching for storing information in user profile then `mixpanel.people.set()` is what you need. Hope it will help you.

Comment: Ok, I think I got the problem with my question and why it is confusing. The users I have are being correctly created in Mixpanel and aliased with a known unique ID (phone number) that I keep in my DB. Now, from a web console that I have, I want to be able to create an HTML link to the corresponding Mixpanel profile: <a href="www.mixpanel.com/some/path/to/user"/> Thats the question

Comment: Oh i see then `mixpanel.get_distinct_id();` is was you need. It will return the distinct id for the user.